# Reference to another field in model.py // Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.11

I would like to return in **str** method of the Chapter, title of the Chapter and title of the Book (from book model). I need it for better display at the admin pages. How to do that?

Should I create some new method in Book or use Model instance reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#model-instance-methods ?
Or maybe I should use Retrieving specific objects with filters?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

I am new to the django, thank you in advance for the solutions.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title+" ("+self.author+")"

    def book_author(self):
        return self.author

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    hierarchy = models.IntegerField()
    sort = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        print(repr(Book))
        print(repr(Book.author))
#       print(repr(Book.objects.all().filter(id==1)))
#        print(repr(Book.objects.get(id=1)))
        print(repr(Book.book_author(self)))
        return self.title+"(book: "+")"
```

Comment: `self.book.author`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s (%s)' % (self.title, self.book.title,)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is so intuitive and nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

To print your object data in admin panel more nicely you should overide `__str__` method for your models.

For example your code should look like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Book with title: {} writen by {}'.format(self.title, self.author)
```

`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I wanted to return title of the Chapter and title of the book in __str__ method of Chapter.

Comment: This was an example. It is simple to adjust it to what you want. Isn't it?

Comment: No, I wanted to use title from Book in Chapter model, self.book.author